# SWT 4.3 browser displays IE 11 incorrectly

Tags: java, internet-explorer, swt

I display html pages in SWT browser. I'm interested in IE 11. External browser displays everything correctly. But internal browser does not (width of droplist shotter than it should be in combobox).

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=11001 in eclipse.ini doesn't help. I know that there is the bug about ie version in windows registry (9.11.9600.16428 instead of 11.0.9600.16428).

And after correction of version in registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Internet Explorer\Version) nothing changed.

i'm using jdk 1.6, windows 7 x64, IE 11, SWT 4.3.

Hi,
After some investigation i found out SWT browser takes IE version from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION.
And everything alright. But the issue is other.
Html combobox displayed wrong in internal IE (any version emulation), when IE 11 installed on computer (when IE8 was installed everything was ok).
Html code:

```
<tr>
    <td>Agreement</td>
    <td>
        <select style="width: 100%;">
            <option>yes</option>
            <option>no</option>
            <option>&nbsp;</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[image]
Select option width equals to option value width, but it should be equal to select width.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, i'm also having the same issue, let me know if there is any possible solution to this problem.